# How to initialize an array in a class constructor

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, initialization

I've looked everywhere and I haven't found anything related to initializing an array in a class constructor.

This is the class I'm trying to create:

```
 public Sandwich(char b, String m, String c, String[] e)
 {
    setBread( b );
    setMeat( m );
    setCheese( c );
    setExtras( e );
 }
```

This is my attempt at initializing the array:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Sandwich[] order;
    order = new Sandwich[3];

    order[0] = new Sandwich('s', "pastrami", "swiss", extras[2] = {"mayo", "extra meat"}  )
    order[1] = new Sandwich();
}
```

I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use `new` to make and array:

```
new Sandwich('s', "pastrami", "swiss", new String[]{"mayo", "extra meat"});
```

Option 2: Use VarArgs:

Redefine your constructor as:

```
public Sandwich(char b, String m, String c, String... e)
```

Passing values to constructor, 4th parameter onwards, all are array elements:

```
new Sandwich('s', "pastrami", "swiss", "mayo", "extra meat");
new Sandwich('s', "pastrami", "swiss", "mayo", "extra meat", "cheese");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
order[0] = new Sandwich('s', "pastrami", "swiss", new String[]{"mayo", "extra meat"} );
```

Refer java tutorial [About array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)